# RestEasy/Guice: Can't inject object into ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, jax-rs, guice, resteasy

I have a `ContainerRequestFilter` to handle request authorization, and I want to inject the implementation of my `AuthService` interface into its constructor (I'm using Guice for DI). I have not been able to figure out how to get the dependency injection to work though.

My filter class looks like this:

```java
public class UserRoleFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

protected AuthService authService;

@Context
private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

@Inject
public UserRoleFilter(AuthService authService) {
    this.authService = authService;
}

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    this.authService.doSomething(...);
}
```

When I run the program though, I get a `NullPointerException` from `org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.<init>`.

My application startup is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new RestApplicationModule(args));
    initServer(injector).join();
}

public static Server initServer(Injector injector) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(SERVER_PORT);
    ServletContextHandler servletHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
    servletHandler.setInitParameter("resteasy.role.based.security", "true");
    servletHandler.setInitParameter("resteasy.providers", UserRoleFilter.class.getName());
    servletHandler.addEventListener(injector.getInstance(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.class));

    servletHandler.addServlet(HttpServletDispatcher.class, "/*");

    // Create the SessionHandler (wrapper) to handle the sessions
    SessionManager manager = new HashSessionManager();
    SessionHandler sessions = new SessionHandler(manager);
    servletHandler.setSessionHandler(sessions);

    server.setHandler(servletHandler);
    server.start();
    return server;
}

private static class RestApplicationModule extends RequestScopeModule {       

    public RestApplicationModule(String[] args) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        super.configure();                     
        bind(AuthService.class).to(AuthServiceImpl.class);
        bind(UserRoleFilter.class);
        // Bind JAX-RS Controller classes
    }
}
```

Stepping through the guts of RestEasy's init code, it looks like I *have* to add the `@Context` attribute to the `authService` parameter in my constructor for RestEasy to acccept it. That passes in a proxy object and allows the server to start, but as soon as the filter tries to access the authService, I get:
`RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: com.genghiszahn.authFilterTest.AuthService`

Comment: After much blind flailing about I solved it, althouh I'm not sure why it worked.

I remove the `setInitParameter` lines from `initServer` and added the @Provider attribute to `UserRoleFilter` and now it's working...

The only thing I can think of is that it's using a different initialization method now.